# Cannot access Horizon Dashboard after log out

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed OpenStack on `Ubuntu 12.04 Server` on `Virtual Box` following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/)

Everything was set up well and I was also able to access `Horizon Dashboard`.

But when I power off `VM` or restart my system then again start `VM` I cannot access, Google Chrome shows

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to
```

I can ping `Adapter 2` from my host OS.

Any solution how to make it working again?

Answer (score 0):

either you rerun your installation script on restart or handle default network configuration files at the restart either in rc.local file and init files so that even if you restart your cloud setting persists!!!!!